# Conceiving an entangling measurement on copies of a two-mode Fock state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

Consider two copies of a general pure two-mode Fock state with a definite number of photons $N$ as follows.

$|\psi\rangle^{\mathrm{TMFS}}=\sum_{n=0}^{N} c_{n}|n\rangle_{a}|N-n\rangle_{b}$ where $c_n$ are generic coefficients and $a$, $b$ are the two modes. Some specific states that fall under this class of states are the [Holland-Burnett states](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.71.1355) and the [N00N states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOON_state) (with both mode and particle entanglement).

In analogy to the [Bell measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state#Bell_state_measurement) on two qubits, how to think of a corresponding entangling measurement that could create entanglement between the two copies of $|\psi\rangle^{\mathrm{TMFS}}$. What would be the entangled two-copy basis for this measurement similar to the [Bell basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state#Bell_basis)?

Further, I would also like to extend it to scenarios that include more than two copies of $|\psi\rangle^{\mathrm{TMFS}}$.

Are there any good references I can go through to think of this problem in a solid way? Thanks.